# Watson Sitemap Laravel Package - Causing Class does not exist issue when adding new page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following laravel package to generate Google XML sitemaps: https://github.com/dwightwatson/sitemap

It's setup like:

```
class SitemapsController extends Controller
{
    public function all()
    {
        $pages = Page::where('active', '=', '1')->get();

        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            Sitemap::addTag(route('page.show', $page->slug), $page->updated_at, 'weekly', '0.8');
        }

        Sitemap::addTag(route('home'), date('Y-m-d'), 'weekly', '0.8');

        return Sitemap::render();
    }
}
```

So relatively simple. However every time a new page is added that should go onto the sitemap it gives me the following error:

> [2016-01-05 07:53:25] local.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Http\Controllers\SitemapsController does not exist' in /home/..../bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:1291

Thinking it was an issue with the package now downloading properly on composer, I did a composer update and there was an update for that package and it sorted it - however it's happened again and I think it's actually sorted when it regenerates the autoload files (which it does on a composer update). Any ideas how to sort this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `php artisan clear-compiled`? Removing the cached `compiled.php` may solve this issue.